# Restrict database for only one user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

i dont know how to ask my question but still i try. I am using SQLServer2008R2. I have created one database say `DB1` and also created one SQLServer user say `User1`. Now I want that only `User1` can have access of `DB1` database and other user can not access to `DB1`.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the `security` node in management studio for your database.

Check that your user is the only login that associated with your database.

If you want to prevent that user creating another user, revoke his permissions to create users.

For more information on users and roles, see the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337552.aspx